# Why do I get permission denied when using make with j flag on Apple Silicon?

Tags: multithreading, makefile, clang, apple-m1

I have a simple make file that compiles a bunch of c files using /opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/clang. I have two machines (an Intel Mac and and Apple M1 Max) both running macOS 12.7.3.

On the Intel Mac: Both *make* and "*make -j8*" compile all the files without issue and as expected.

On the Apple M1 Max: When I run *make* without any flags, it compiles all the files without problem.  However, if run *"make -j8"*, I get: *make: /opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/clang: Permission denied*.  If I run  *"sudo make -j8"*, then I do not get permission denied.

Why does running make with multiple threads give permission denied on Apple M1 Max but not Intel Macs even though both are running macOS 12.7.3 and both are using the same version of clang (17.0.6)?

I tried changing the owner and permissions on /opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin/clang.  I tried many different make files (all have the same issue).  I tried changing the number of threads. "-j1" works, but "-j2" and higher fail.  I was expecting that the using the -j8 on the Apple M1 Max would simply use multiple threads to compile all the files more quickly.  Could there be some security feature in the Apple M1 Max chips that prevents users from running multi-threaded jobs in the terminal?  My account has admin privileges.

Comment: This is a fair, on-topic question, but I'm doubtful that you will find an answer here, unless this happens to be a known flaw in the Homebrew build of `make`.  Homebrew support channels would probably be a better venue for this matter.

Comment: The question shows that clang is being run from homebrew but not make.  Do you use homebrew make or the Apple version of make?  What does `type -a make` show on each system, and what does `make --version` show on each system?  Are you setting output sync options (`-O`) for example in `GNUMAKEFLAGS`?

Comment: This question is unanswerable unless you provide the necessary steps to reproduce the issue.

Comment: The problem was due to Apple's make.  I updated the question with a more detailed description of the solution.  Thanks!

Comment: Your question should remain strictly a question; please don't add your own solution to it. You are welcome to post it as an actual answer in the "Post Your Answer" box below. (The text of the edit I rolled back is still available from the [revision history.)](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78107787/revisions)

Comment: Sorry, I saw the "Use comments to..." message in the add comment text box.  So, I thought you wanted it there.  I did not see the "Answer you comment" button until just now. Thank you for moving the text around for me and changing the status.

Answer (score 0):

*Editor's note: I have moved this from the question into an answer, and marked the answer as Community-owned.  OP, if you would rather post this as an answer of your own, leave a comment and ask me to delete this so it won't complete with your own answer.*

Using `gmake` probably entails first installing it from Homebrew or etc.

---

On both systems:

```
zsh% type -a make
make is /usr/bin/make

zsh% make --version
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
This program built for i386-apple-darwin11.3.0
```

When I switch to `gmake`, everything works properly on both machines.  So the culprit is Apple's ancient `make`.  Thanks to John Bolinger and MadScientist for pointing me in the right direction!